# Static and Dynamic Libraries

Tags: c++, dynamic, static, libraries, sfml

I am using SFML, and I am building an application in Code::Blocks and mingw32. I have have added the SFML libraries (sfml-whatever.a) to my project, and it runs nicely.

BUT iIrc, the static libraries get 'compiled' into the executable. If this is so, then why do I have to place all the SFML DLL's next to the executable for it to run anywhere outside of Code::Blocks? And if I were to somehow 'dynamically link' the DLL's from within Code::Blocks to my project, (I don't know how to do that), would I still have to ship my executable with all the .a files for it to run properly?

Thanks in advance, I am not quite familiar with libraries, static or dynamic. If it makes any difference, I am working on Ubuntu linux, and I am using mingw32 for cross-compiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the static libraries simply contain the code that interfaces to the dynamic libraries, it's not the actual library code.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. So, if I understand correctly, I will still have to link to the static libraries, but keep the DLL's next to the executable?

Comment: @Keelx: Yes, unless there's an option to link statically.

Answer (score 6):

With SFML you can link statically to their libraries as mentioned in the comments above. This way its all compiled into the executable and you won't need to ship it with the DLL's. How this is done depends on whether you are using SFML 1.6 or 2.0.

1.6 doesn't require any preprocessor definitions, but 2.0 requires you to build a solution/makefile using cmake for your compiler and then #define `SFML_STATIC` in your preprocessor definitions.